# Kotlin function for invoking another function until condition satisfied

Tags: kotlin, generics

I wrote some code but I couldn't make Kotlin to compile it

That's what I have

```kotlin
// Puppy - stuff
data class Puppy(private val name: String)
fun findPuppy(id: UUID): () -> Puppy? = TODO()

// Class which instance will store condition to stop calling
class Requirement<T>(private val predicate: (T) -> Boolean) {
    fun because(errorMessage: String) : ReasonableRequirement<T> {
        return ReasonableRequirement(this, errorMessage)
    }
}

// Decorator class for proving 
data class ReasonableRequirement<T>(private val requirement: Requirement<T>, private val failMessage: String)

// Smart function itself
fun <T> (() -> T?).invokeUntil(requirement: ReasonableRequirement<T>) : T = TODO()

// Class for storing general requirements that will be unique for every case 
class Requirements {
    companion object {
        fun <T> isNotNull() = Requirement { x: T -> x != null}
    }
}

fun main() {
    val reasonableReq: ReasonableRequirement<Puppy?> = isNotNull().because("Puppy must be found") // 1
    val foundPuppy : Puppy = findPuppy(UUID.randomUUID()).invokeUntil(reasonableReq) // 2
    println(foundPuppy)
}
```

I expected this code to work. However

`1` doesn't compile. Intelij says:

```
Not enough information to infer type variable T
```

`2` doesn't compile too. Intelij says:

```
Required: Puppy
Found:    Puppy?
```

My questions are:
1. Can it be actullay implemented in Kotlin? (because I started worrying)

```kotlin
val foundPuppy = findPuppy(randomid).invokeUntil(isNotNull.because("Puppy must be found")) // <-- returns Puppy, not Puppy?
```

2. If so, how do I implement `invokeUntill`-function signature and `isNotNull` - variable for all cases?

I.e how do I fix it so everything in `main` would be compiled and generics would not dissappear?

Important note: I expect to make it **exactly like above** so

1. No `{` and `}` should be used
2. No explicits casts or using something like `<Puppy?> should be done either

Comment: What kind of problem you are trying to solve? Seems to me like the task in the title of the question can be implemented in much simpler way via recursive function/loop

Comment: Implementations of `findPuppy` and `invokeUntil` are important though

Comment: @Steyrix hello. I decided to not provide implementation of these functions because they do not provide useful information to my current task. I want to Kotlin make it compile.

Comment: @Steyrix I agree that my problem can be solved in much simpler ways  but this one is preferable cuz it has syntax I expect to have in my tests

Comment: Anton, I left my suggestion to implementation as an answer. Please try it and edit, extend your question if you will still have troubles

Comment: Did you have an ability to review the answer?

Answer (score 1):

*I am not at my PC and my answer can be inaccurate*

`val isNotNull = Requirement<Any?>{t -> t != null}`

Above is not a generic method/variable. It forces compiler to try to take `Requirement<Puppy?>` as `Requirement<Any?>`.

More accurate way would be to do it like below:

```
fun <T> isNotNull(t: T) = Requirement<T> { x: T -> x != null}
```

Then the `val foundPuppy : Puppy` should be `val foundPuppy: Puppy?`. It seems slightly confusing, since you are requiring that puppy is not null, however compiler cannot guarantee it unless you will use not nullable types all along the flow.

**UPD:**

```
val reasonableReq: ReasonableRequirement<Puppy?> = isNotNull().because("Puppy must be found") // 1
```

Line above will not compile for 2 reasons. It has type `ReasonableRequirement`, but the value to the right side of `=` has type `Requirement<T>`.

Secondly, you should tell the compiler, which type you want to substitute generic value with.

```
val reasonableReq: Requirement<Puppy> = isNotNull<Puppy>().because("Puppy must be found") // 1
```

And answering your question

> Can it be actullay implemented in Kotlin? (because I started worrying)

It can if you somehow guarantee to the compiler that there will be no case, when puppy will not be found at all. For that you should not use nullable types (e.g. `Puppy?`).

Comment: Thanks. You can remove function argument, its not necessary. You were almost right, expression `val req : Requirement<Puppy?> = isNotNull()` compiles but I faced another problem (Updated my answer, see code)

Comment: @GromovAnton updated the answer